# Multiple loops/Lines at the same time

Tags: python, loops, python-3.9

is it possible to run a while loop and other lines of code at the same time?
I've tried to run multiple while loops but what I made is a balance.
**Here is my try**

```
parity = 0
while True:
    while parity%2 == 0:
        print('running')
        parity += 1
    while parity &  1 :
        print('True')
        parity +=1
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Not unless you use multi-threading or some kind of parallel programming. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html Maybe [edit] your question to include what you're trying to do and why you need multiple loops running concurrently? This smells like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/174780).

Comment: Briefly, I want to run two loops whatever they are parallel to each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
for parity in range(ANY_NUMBER):
    if parity%2 == 0:
        print('running')
    if parity &  1 :
        print('True')

    if not final_condition:
        break
```

I don't think while loops are recommended here.
You can replace final_condition by any condition and if it is True, it will stop the loop